# fire simulation start frame

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation, fire

I'm trying to do a fire simulation that should look like a meteor. I have applied quick smoke, then smoke and fire on the physics tab but the fire appears right after 100 frames, too late for what I am trying to do.
How can I control the exact frame where the fire should appear?
I want the fire to appear right on frame 1.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just start your animation frame 100.

[image]

And keep the domain start frame at 0.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! At first I tried changing the start frame as you said first, but that didn't work, so I did put it back to 1 and notice that the domain frame start was in 1 and "Is Resumable" was not checked as you show in your picture. So I put it on 0, checked Is Resumable and just got fire at frame 1. thank you again!

Comment: You are welcome!